# Java Multi-threading Deadlock or Starvation?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, thread-synchronization, starvation

I am learning for my OCP exam and are trying to understand when we are speaking of a thread deadlock or a thread is in starvation. in case of the scenario below I have doubt.

```
public class ThreadTest {

private static int i = 0;
    
public static void doSomething() {
synchronized(ThreadTest.class) {
    while(true) {
      System.out.println("count:" + ++i)
    } }
}

public static void main(String args[]) { 
New Thread(() -> doSomething()).start();
New Thread(() -> doSomething()).start();
}}
```

The first thread to acquires the lock of the synchronized ThreadTest class in doSomething() goes in a infinite loop never releasing the lock.
The second thread keep waiting til the resource becomes available (what never happens).

Are we speaking of a Deadlock in this situation or Starvation? I think about Starvation because one thread is not getting access to a shared resource and for a deadlock threads block each others resources. But just to be sure i ask about it here.

Deadlock describes a situation where threads are blocked forever.

Starvation describes a situation where a thread is unable to gain regular access to shared resources.

Comment: There are 4 necessary and sufficient conditions for deadlock, one of which is circular waiting for locks, which you can't be doing here as there is only one lock being acquired.

Comment: Look at your own descriptions of deadlock and starvation. Which of the two is happening here? Are both threads waiting and blocked or is one of the threads doing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comment. Deadlock happens when the below 4 conditions happens. Them being :

1. Mutual Exclusion - B wants a resource A has. B cannot use the
   resource A is using(which is happening here).
2. Hold and wait - A is holding a resource that B wants. A is also waiting for a resource to be freed that somebody else has(Not happening for A from the probem statement given)
3. No Preemption - The resource A is holding cannot be snatched away from it by force(assuming that it is true here because not given other wise).
4. Circular Wait - A is holding a resouce B wants. B is holding a resource A wants(Not happening here).

Hence we see here that all the conditions are not met. So a deadlock cannot exist in this situation.

There is however an infinite loop due to which A never gives up the lock. Hence B will be starved.

This should clear your doubt. Cheers